# ERROR 1064 (42000) when creating database in mysql

Tags: mysql

in mysql interactive terminal, when I want to create a new database

```
mysql> create database albedo-new;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-new' at line 1
```

I'm not sure whether mysql allow '-' in a database name.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

mysql does allow hyphens in database names

use backticks

```
create database `albedo-new`
```

Comment: It's better to not use hyphens at all ... see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html for valid unquoted identifiers.

Comment: correct, i only ever use lower case letters and numbers for database, table and column names. as quoting is a pain in the ass